# How to get ratio of scale image, when it's autoscaled by background-cover?

Tags: jquery, css, scale

I have some problems:

I need to bind some text to positions om image (you know, like marks on redpen.io an other services). Text is binded to big image, well, like 1900x1200px.

Then on other pages I add this image to background of element, stretched to all window:

```
#backg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: 'url-to-big-image.jpg'
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And then i have troubles: I can't bind my saved marks to this element! 
First, I divide original height and width of element to window height and width: Qh and Qw.
I take original **top** and **left** css of mark, then multiply top*Qh and Qw*left.

It works for width, but not for height! It's somehow scaled by browser, and position of elements on image doesn't match.

How can I get ratio of height scaling, to position my marks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the 'Hard' issue, the answer was quite simple, though not obvious :) All the matter between scales:

First, we need to find coefficients of ratio between "real" height and width of picture and shown in the background:

```
var imgSize = new Image();
imgSize.onload = function() {
    $('#ourdiv').css('background-image', 'url("' + imgSize.src + '")');
    h_real = this.height;
    w_real = this.width;

    q_h = h_real / $(window).height();
    q_w = w_real / $(window).width();
};
imgSize.src = 'path_to_img.jpg';
```

Then, divide our "real" positions of element to coef's. However,depending on whether the coefficient is greater, we should divide on another:

```
if (q_w > q_h)
    {
        top_d = Math.round(top_d / q_h);   
        left_d = Math.round(left_d / q_h);
    }
else
    {
        top_d = Math.round(top_d / q_w);   
        left_d = Math.round(left_d / q_w);        
    }
```

And voila! - all elements on same places!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help you with so few lines of code.

I tried to provide a simple improvment by changing this following CSS lines:

```
#backg {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

You can play with it on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/D2wQ4/1).

Is it what you are looking for?

---

**[UPDATE]**

You can use the padding-top trick to have a container that fit to the image size.

```
#backg {
    height: 0;
    padding-top: <image-ratio>%;
}
```

You can play with it on [this updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/D2wQ4/2).

Cheers,
Thomas.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas, but it's not exactly what I was looking for :) You see, in your example image is loaded without aspect ratio, but I need to keep it. But, anyway, big thank you for your help, it gave me some prog :) Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Maybe, you can just show me direction, where i should start? I will be grateful for any hint :)

Comment: Did the new solution help you?

Comment: Sorry for late response, tzi :) Unfortunately, this is not what I was looking for, but it's a great piece of code, anyway! I did some experiments and found solution exactly for my terms. I post it in this thread :) Thank you very much for attention!